# org.apache.http.params is deprecated where i have sdk version 25?

Tags: android

App won't build with error related to 'org.apache.http.legacy' library how can i resolve the error "this inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope"

as 'org.apache.http.legacy' Library is imported, and optional.JSON file is existing in its path which contains the below

```
{
    "name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
    "jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
    "manifest": false
  }
```

and also org.apache.http.legacy jar file is existing in the same path 
\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\optional

noting that i have targetSdkVersion 25 and android studio 2.2.3

Comment: Deprecated shouldn't prevent from building and running the application, are you sure you don't have lintOptions enabled with the following attributes.
    -checkAllWarnings true
    -warningsAsErrors true
    -abortOnError true

Comment: Thanks @ViVekH that's true.. App works but it doesn't send data to server  ! does it related to Deprecated ??

Comment: nope, debug and check if the http request is being formed properly and check if you are getting an error response.